# print page using Rotativa in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rotativa

I am using Rotativa to print page in my application in asp.net mvc .

it is work well but my problems is i want to print the filter data .

For example, I have Position tables and Teachers , so when click to Position A the all teacher of the Position A show  and i put link for print inside each Position.

this is my controller :

```
  public ActionResult IndexById(int? id)
    {
        var teachersD = db.TeacherDetails.AsQueryable().Include(s => s.Position);
        if (id != null) teachersD = teachersD.Where(c => c.PositionId == id);
        ViewBag.result = teachersD;
        return View(teachersD.ToList());
    }


    public ActionResult Print(int id)
    {
        var report = new ActionAsPdf("IndexById", new { PositionId = id });
        return report;
    }
```

and this View :

```
 <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Teacher", "Index", "TeacherDetails", new { id = item.Id }, null)
    </td>

    <td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Print ", "Print", new { id = item.Id })

    </td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing a value called `PositionId`:

```
new ActionAsPdf("IndexById", new { PositionId = id })
```

But the action is expecting a value called `id`:

```
public ActionResult IndexById(int? id)
```

The framework's model/value binding is based on the names, so they need to match.  Since `id` is missing in the request, the value ends up being `null`.  (If it was an `int` instead of an `int?` you would get an error about a missing required value.)

Simply pass the value as `id`:

```
new ActionAsPdf("IndexById", new { id = id })
```

Comment: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Abu_Bilal.Models.TeacherDetails]', but this dictionary
requires a model item of type
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Abu_Bilal.Models.Position]'

Comment: @programmer: Sounds like your `IndexById` action/view currently doesn't work as expected, outside the context of this PDF functionality.  You're passing a `List<TeacherDetails>` to the view, but the error indicates that the view expects an `IEnumerable<Position>`?  (Either that or the PDF library isn't used the way you expect?)  What is the view for `IndexById`?

Comment: @programmer: As an aside, why do you store your model in the `ViewBag` *and* send the model to the view directly?  The former isn't necessary at all.

Comment: what i can do now ?

Comment: @programmer: What is the `@model` declaration in the `IndexById` view?  Is there a `Print` view?  If so, what is it's `@model` declaration?  Does the vendor for this PDF library provide an example demonstrating what you're trying to do?  What is that example?